# How do I view the animation I rendered?

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I had finished my animation, rendered the whole thing overnight, and when I came to my desktop in the morning, it was finished. (I am an amateur at this, so don't judge) The animation has rendered, now how do I watch it?

I would like an up-to-date answer to my question, and please explain. I am using the latest Blender (At least when I made this question) version 2.8. I've tried to press the folder button, but that just said "Open Image", and then there was "New Image", which I didn't want to have to render it again. Maybe I did it wrong.  I did Render, render animation. Or Ctrl + F12 for short. Please help, I am new to this!

Comment: Did you set a location to where it would go?

Comment: Ctrl F11, or load the images into any video editing program (like Blenders Video Sequencer).

Comment: You can use any movie viewing app to watch your video. Try downloading VLC

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to render an animation in blender:

1. Render as Video
2. Render as Image Sequence

My suggestion is to use the second method (Render as Image Sequence) for having a list of benefits:

- you'll have all the single frames not compresses (best settings are saving single frames as PNG or any lossless image type), so if you need to edit something later on you can do it
- you'll decode the video after, so you can always change the compression and format (just use ffmpeg to get quicker and best results) (if you just render the animation as video in Blender and if you select a compression too low, you cannot fix that later)
- if your computer crash you'll have the single frames (if it crashes while rendering the video, I fear you'll get a corrupted video in the best scenario, you'll get nothing in the worst scenario)

Your file (or files) are in the folder you specified as OUTPUT (in the output properties).
It can be also in the TMP folder. In this case you need to find out where the TMP folder is on your pc by typing %tmp% in your windows search bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can open your movie or image sequence in Blender itself: Create 2 *Video Sequencer* windows, keep one as a *Sequencer*, switch the second one as *Preview*, in the *Sequencer* press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and load your movie: *Image/Sequence* if it's a series of images (as explained Sanbaldo you can render a series of images instead of a movie), or *Movie* if it's a movie. Keep in mind that the movie or images won't be saved inside the blend file itself, it will always catch it in the folder where it is in your computer.

[image]